# Moving file using apache commons FileUtils does not always succeed

Tags: java, file, apache-commons

I am watching a directory using java.nio.file.WatchService. When a new file is dropped in the directory then I read the file and move it to a backup directory. The following piece of code moves file from source to destination.

```
private void backUpFile(Path source, String destination) {
        System.out.println("Backing up into " + destination);
        try {
            // Files.copy(source, destination);
            String fileName = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(source.getFileName().toString().toLowerCase()) + "_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmssSSS'.csv'").format(new Date());
            FileUtils.moveFile(FileUtils.getFile(source.toAbsolutePath().toString()), FileUtils.getFile(
                    destination + "\\" + fileName));

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Back up done!");
    }
```

This works good in my local computer. But when I do the same operation in a remote VM (copy & paste files), sometimes few files are not deleted after the move operation, even though it creates files in the destination directory. It does not print any error log. What could be the issue?

Comment: Instead of `FileUtils.getFile(source.toAbsolutePath().toString())`, why not simply `source.toAbsolutePath().toFile()`?

Comment: Instead of `FileUtils.getFile(destination + "\\" + fileName)`, just do `FileUtils.getFile(destination, fileName)` - then you won't be restricted to Windows only. Or `new File(destination, fileName)`.

Comment: Most likely cause is that `moveFile` is trying to delete the original file while the process that created the file has not yet closed it (so is considered to be still in use). Wait for the other process to close the file before attempting to move the file.